# Unable to fetch data in JSON format from API into Spotfire

Tags: python, ironpython

The API which i am trying to fetch data looks like this "https://repositery-api.appication-pp.ag/v10/repositeries/?page=0&size=1"

and the iron python code which i am trying to fetch data in JSON format is

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
clr.AddReference('System.Web.Extensions')
import System
from System import DateTime
from System.Data import DataSet, DataTable
from System.IO import StreamReader, StreamWriter, MemoryStream, SeekOrigin
from System.Net import HttpWebRequest
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
from System import String, Int32, Single, Double
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataType, DataTableSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import import TextFileDataSource, TextDataReaderSettings

# get data in JSON format
uri = "https://repositery-api.appication-pp.ag/v10/repositeries/?page=0&size=1"
print uri

webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
response = webRequest.GetResponse()
streamReader = StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
jsonData = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
js = JavaScriptSerializer()
js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
**dataDict = js.Deserialize(jsonData,object)**
```

i am getting error saying **" Invalid JSON primitive: ."** from the last line of the code .
can someone please look into this and help me out

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "a": "CHEMISTRY",
            "b": 1,
            "c": "Hc",
            "d": 12345,
            "d": "k7t3h0t-jk78-0bnp-0t25-7fg5335gf78b",
            "e": {
                "f": "95366",
                "g": "57998",
                "h": "BALKIJ",
                "i": ""
            },
            "j": {
                "k": 1389,
                "l": "2004-11-25T10:96:41Z",
                "j": "balkij",
                "k": "CHEMISTRY ",
                "l": 12345,
                "e": {
                    "m": "574.0",
                    "n": "3",
                    "o": " BALKIJ ",
                    "p": "ERR098",
                    "q": "jdnd kskd"
                },
                "r": false
            },
            "s": null,
            "t": 96652,
            "u": "98852",
            "v": null,
            "w": null,
            "x": "2004-11-25T10:96:67Z ",
            "y": "hjjn",
            "z": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: at least show use the faulty data. If that's not possible due to confidentiality, can you mock up some data? You should also try to feed it some data which you know is valid

Comment: @MaartenFabré Edited the original post 
please find the "SAMPLE DATA" section

Comment: There is a `"` missing and there are some `¬` signs. Is this also in the real data?

Comment: Sorry while mocking up data those got added 
i removed '¬' and added '"' to  'K' element

Comment: it sounds like you're retrieving invalid JSON, so this is going to be difficult to answer without actual data. I suggest collecting whatever is returned from the API as a string and putting it through a JSON validator like jsonlint.com .

Comment: @niko I did that and it doesn't return any error saying "Valid Json" .Thanks

Comment: you will not get an invalid JSON error unless you have invalid JSON. I don't mean to be obstinate, but that's what this error means. your response may be getting cut off or something, but whatever the case, you are being given JSON that is not parsable by the serializer.